# How can I display an option screen when a user disconnects a call?

Tags: android

How can I display an option screen when a user disconnects a call?

[image]

Comment: You might want to hide the phone number from the picture for security reasons

Comment: no i will display option ..for my application.

Comment: i meant from the question you posted, the pic u have uploaded. Hope its not a personal number of a friend....?

Comment: ok ok .. i find this picture from google,thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Check PhoneStateListener here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

You may also try these tutorials:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200207220537/http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-listen-phone-events-android

https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html

Just log all state changes to check what state is being triggered when you hangup.

Answer (score 0):

It detects hangup button key events.

```
  @Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
  int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
  if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL) {
        //do your work here
        return true;
     } else {
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
     }
  }
}
```